# Resizing an input image in a Keras Lambda layer

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I would like my `keras` model to resize the input image using OpenCV or similar.

I have seen the use of `ImageGenerator`, but I would prefer to write my own generator and simply resize the image in the first layer with `keras.layers.core.Lambda`.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are using tensorflow backend then you can use `tf.image.resize_images()` function to resize the images in `Lambda` layer.

Here is a small example to demonstrate the same:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from keras.layers import Lambda, Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.backend import tf as ktf


# 3 channel images of arbitrary shape
inp = Input(shape=(None, None, 3))
try:
    out = Lambda(lambda image: ktf.image.resize_images(image, (128, 128)))(inp)
except :
    # if you have older version of tensorflow
    out = Lambda(lambda image: ktf.image.resize_images(image, 128, 128))(inp)

model = Model(input=inp, output=out)
model.summary()

X = scipy.ndimage.imread('test.jpg')

out = model.predict(X[np.newaxis, ...])

fig, Axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
Axes[0].imshow(X)
Axes[1].imshow(np.int8(out[0,...]))

plt.show()
```

Comment: I've run into the same problem as before.  At prediction time, I get an error that `ktf` is not found.  I applied the same import statement in my prediction script of course.  I also changed to a full path as `keras.backend.tf` and still `NameError`: name `keras` is not defined

Comment: @SamHammamy It seems the environment where you are running the predict script don't have keras. Try importing only keras and see. If it works see which backend its using. Also instead of getting `tf` from keras backend, you can use `import tensorflow as tf` and use the same.

Comment: Of course it has `keras`.  I ran the prediction by resizing in the `generator` for weeks.  It is however a Raspberry Pi board and I installed TensorFlow on it from a custom pip wheel I found online.  As I said it works fine if I resize in the generator.  I also found this solution which I need to investigate today https://gist.github.com/bzamecnik/a33052ec46ee7efeb217856d98a4fb5f

Comment: I could get this to work either `model.add(Lambda(lambda image: K.resize_images(image, 240./64, 340./64, 'tf')))`  I get a resource exhausted error during training even with only 32 images in a batch

Comment: There are few things which you can do.. train on system. when you have a good set of weights use it to run on the embedded system.. this will decrease the memory requirement on the embedded system by the batch size. 2nd use theano backend.. tensorflow is more memory hungry.

Comment: I was training on a `p2.xlarge` instance on AWS.  I know I wasn't clear in saying that.  I think the problem is on the Pi at prediction time.  Anyhow, I don't want to spend too much time on this.  If I resize in my generator and resize on the Pi before prediction, all is well.  Thanks again!

Comment: Use tf.image.resize function instead of resize_images.
ktf no longer supports resize_images method.