# Loading Keras model from google cloud ml bucket

Tags: model, keras, google-cloud-platform, load, google-cloud-ml

Using Keras on Google cloud ml:

Saving model from training:

model.save('model.h5')

```
if cfg.cloud:
    # Copy model.h5 over to Google Cloud Storage
    with file_io.FileIO('model.h5', mode='rb') as input_f:
        with file_io.FileIO(data_folder + 'model.h5', mode='wb+') as output_f:
            output_f.write(input_f.read())
```

Note: not saving to job_folder, I need to read this later, not wanting to keep track of the latest job (even if that's a good way to keep models apart).

Now I want to read from my next run:

```
f = file_io.FileIO(model_file, mode='rb')
model = load_model(f)
model.load_weights(f)
```

Where 'model_file' is given as input in my submission, pointing at

```
--model-file gs://$BUCKET_NAME/resources/model.h5
```

Complains from google cloud ml jobs:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileIO
```

I tried a number of things, but my basic question is: what's the best practice writing *and especially* reading in models from gcp buckets?

Comment: Please clarify where in code this exception occurs, is it in your code at your load_model(f) or is it in sdk code?

Comment: Thanks Oliver, I did some debugging to answer your question in more detail, and while doing that I found the solution below.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I got it working, using the solution here:

[loading saved keras model from gs to pydatalab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48392457/loading-saved-keras-model-from-gs-to-pydatalab)

Thanks Tíarnán McGrath (I don't have enough points to do a plus 1)

Comment: Which is to copy model file from gs to local filesystem, right?

Comment: @user2427317 you can accept your answer (consider editing adding the important information)