# How can we import MNIST images instead of dataframe.?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, mnist, resnet

I am trying to run MNIST dataset on ResNet50 using keras. 
I am stuck on the part where ImageDatagenerator is used on the mnist dataset as available in keras to import file from directory. If I understand the `data_generator.flow_from_directory` correctly then it is asking for the path of images as its first argument,.

However I am not able to figure out how to input these mnist data as it is available.

I know that the file available in `from keras.datasets import mnist` is imported as a dataframe. whereas the `flow_from_directory('../input/train',..)` is asking for the paths to images

Any help would be appreciated.

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

image_size = 224
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator() 
import pandas
train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        '../input/train',
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        batch_size=200,
        class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        '../input/val',
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        class_mode='categorical')
```

Answer (score 1):

Mnist Dataset is integrated with keras. You can use it as follows

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

In this case you will not need ImageDataGenerator. You can just fit the tuples returned to your model

```
model.fit(x= x_train, y= y_train, validation_data= (x_test,y_test))
```

Source - [keras datasets](https://keras.io/datasets/) 
Source - [Model class API](https://keras.io/models/model/)

**Edit:**
As for the Resnet, you can try using a Lambda layer to resize the images
[Link to SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260265/resizing-an-input-image-in-a-keras-lambda-layer)

The other alternative is to convert your dataframes into numpy arrays and use the fit function shown in the code above

Comment: But input image to resnet is of the form 224 x224 and mnist is of 28x28

Comment: yea, tf.image.resize_image does that with tensors

Answer (score 0):

Find MNIST as JPG (https://www.kaggle.com/scolianni/mnistasjpg) and use it. 
From your code ('../input/train') I am guessing that you are using Kaggle kernel. You can simply add data to notebook via +AddData button on your right and searcing for MNIST as JPG. However I have found strange bug here - the kernel didn't read the MNIST database. Workaround was to download MNIST as JPG, unpack locally, then pack again and upload to private database before using).