# Resizing to bigger resolution with skimage causes shape typeerror in keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, typeerror, scikit-image

My goal is to take a pre-trained model without the last two fully connected layers to build new my own classier for CIFAR-10. The first problem I have faced is that VGG expects at least `48*48*3` tensor while CIFAR-10 dataset comes with `32*32*3` images. I know that `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory` comes with built-in `target_size` parameter but I can't use it here because images are already in memory:

```
from keras.applications import VGG16
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
vgg_conv = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(48, 48, 3)) # 48 its a minimum width 

>> type(x_train) #we have numpy here
numpy.ndarray
```

For transforming the images I'm using `skimage` (don't know why but it seems to work):

```
from  skimage import transform
new_shape = (48,88,3)
x_train = np.asarray([transform.resize(image, new_shape) for image in x_train])
```

Next we pass it to generator in order to be able to feed NN with batches. Unfortunately it doesn't have `target_size` parameter, so I used `resize` before:

```
train_generator = datagen.flow(
    x_train, 
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    shuffle=True)
```

Then I'm iterating over `train_generator` with no luck:

```
for inputs_batch  in train_generator:
    features_batch = vgg_conv.predict(inputs_batch)
    train_features[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch 
    i += 1
    if i * batch_size >= nImages:
        break
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
>       ----> 2     features_batch = vgg_conv.predict(inputs_batch)
>   ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_4 to have shape (48, 48, 3) but got array with shape (48, 88, 3)

The problem might be related to `flow generator`, which:

```
    # Returns
        An `Iterator` yielding tuples of `(x, y)`
            where `x` is a numpy array of image data
            (in the case of a single image input) or a list
            of numpy arrays (in the case with
            additional inputs) and `y` is a numpy array
            of corresponding labels. If 'sample_weight' is not None,
        the yielded tuples are of the form `(x, y, sample_weight)`.
        If `y` is None, only the numpy array `x` is returned.
```

So I have 2 questions: what is wrong here and is there any better way to resize image, maybe some built in to Keras function?

Comment: You have a typo here: `new_shape = (48,88,3)`; it should be `new_shape = (48,48,3)` i.e. `48` not `88` as the error says.

Comment: As for resizing the images you can also try the solution provided in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42262632/2099607). The advantage of the mentioned solution is that it would be part of the model and you can feed the model with images of arbitrary size.

Comment: And don't forget to normalize the images by passing `rescale=1/255.` to `ImageDataGenerator`.

Comment: @today It worked, could you just copypast your comment to answer. So I will be able to close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**Note:** [as per requested by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126531/resizing-to-bigger-resolution-with-skimage-causes-shape-typeerror-in-keras?noredirect=1#comment89280113_51126531), I have combined my comments into this answer.)

1. You have a typo here: `new_shape = (48,88,3)`; it should be `new_shape = (48,48,3)`, i.e. `48` not `88` as the error says.
2. Don't forget to normalize the images by passing `rescale=1./255` to `ImageDataGenerator`.
3. As for resizing the images, your current approach is fine. But you can also try the solution provided in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42262632/2099607). The advantage of the mentioned solution is that it would be part of the model and you can feed the model with images of arbitrary size.