# How to write a custom resize layer that takes a resize value from an Input layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I am trying to add a custom resize layer that does not have a fixed resize value, instead, it takes a scale value from an input layer.

I found this but it has a fixed resize value: [Add a resizing layer to a keras sequential model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903928/add-a-resizing-layer-to-a-keras-sequential-model)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

class Resize(Layer):
    def init(self):
        super(Resize,self).__init__()

    def build(self,input_shape):
        super(Resize,self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x, size):
        out = tf.image.resize(x,size=size) 
        return out
    def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):
        return (None,None,3)


inp = Input((10,10,3))
size = Input((1,), dtype='int32')

out = Resize()(inp, size=(100,100)) #(inp, size=(size,size))

model = Model([inp,size], out)
model.summary()
```

When I try this:

```
inp = Input((10,10,3))
size = Input((1,), dtype='int32')

out = Resize()(inp, size=(size,size))

model = Model([inp,size], out)
model.summary()
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/api/_v1/keras/models/__init__.py in <module>()
      2 size = Input((1,), dtype='int32')
      3 
----> 4 out = Resize()(inp, size=(size,size)) #(inp, size=(size,size))
      5 
      6 model = Model([inp,size], out)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    634                     outputs = base_layer_utils.mark_as_return(outputs, acd)
    635                 else:
--> 636                   outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    637 
    638             except TypeError as e:

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    147       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    148         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 149           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(type(e))
    150         else:
    151           raise

ValueError: in converted code:

    <ipython-input-1-ab7021ffbc7d>:14 call *
        out = tf.image.resize(x,size=size)
    /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py:1182 resize_images
        skip_resize_if_same=True)
    /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py:1045 _resize_images_common
        raise ValueError('\'size\' must be a 1-D Tensor of 2 elements: '

    ValueError: 'size' must be a 1-D Tensor of 2 elements: new_height, new_width


​
```

Comment: I think the answer from @fzyzcjy in your link has provided the answer you want.

Comment: the issue with that is I get an error related to the tensor. The Input layer would produce a tensor and this would expect only an int data type.

Comment: It's better provide some example codes you have tried. It would help find out your bugs.

Comment: Hi, I just edited my sample code here. Thanks.

Comment: What's your error?

Comment: with this approach, the error is: `ValueError: 'size' must be a 1-D Tensor of 2 elements: new_height, new_width`

Comment: From the error info, seems you didn't input 1-d tensor of 2 elements into `tf.image.resize`. Could you post the codes you run and the completed Traceback.

Comment: I get the error when I run this: `inp = Input((10,10,3))
size = Input((1,), dtype='int32')

out = Resize()(inp, size=(size,size))
model = Model([inp,size], out)` .  Note: Please see the edits now.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to set `size=Input(tensor=K.variable([2,2], dtype=tf.int32))`.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

class Resize(Layer):
    def init(self):
        super(Resize,self).__init__()

    def build(self,input_shape):
        super(Resize,self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = inputs[0]
        size = inputs[1]
        out = tf.image.resize(x,size=size) 
        return out
    def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):
        return (None,None,3)


inp = Input((10,10,3))
var_size = K.variable([2,2], dtype=tf.int32)
size = Input(tensor=var_size, name='size')

out = Resize()([inp, size])

model = Model([inp,size], out)
model.summary()

# Model: "model"
# __________________________________________________________________________________________________
# Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
# ==================================================================================================
# input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 10, 10, 3)]  0                                            
# __________________________________________________________________________________________________
# input_2 (InputLayer)            [(2,)]               0                                            
# __________________________________________________________________________________________________
# resize (Resize)                 (None, None, None, 3 0           input_1[0][0]                    
#                                                                  input_2[0][0]                    
# ==================================================================================================
# Total params: 0
# Trainable params: 0
# Non-trainable params: 0

input_mat = np.random.randn(100,10,10,3)
K.set_value(var_size, [5,5])
res = model.predict({'x': input_mat})
# res.shape (100,5,5,3)

K.set_value(var_size, [3,3])
res = model.predict({'x': input_mat})
# res.shape (100,3,3,3)
```

Comment: will this take any input size when predicting? I just tried compiling and using `model.predict([arr, [5,5]])`, the output size is (2,2,3) only.

Comment: The initialized value of size is (2,2), you can assign new size to this variable.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Is it possible to pass a value while predicting?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer. You can `K.set_value` to set different size for the variable.

Comment: Thank you. Can this also work while training? I want to train the model with variable sizes.

Comment: It depends on your network. If you have fc layer, then you cannot change input size while training.